# How do we display custom text on each resources date cell?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm setting up a calendar with fullcalendar-scheduler. How do we add custom text on each date cell of particular resources?

I have tried adding through dayRender() function, but it only adds for one specific date but not on every dates of different resources.

```
$('#fleet_calendar').fullCalendar({
    selectable: true,
    defaultView: 'timelineEightDays',
    defaultDate: this.state.defaultDate,
    views: {
    timelineEightDays: {
        type: 'timeline',
        duration: { days: 8 },
        slotDuration: '24:00'
    }
    },
    header: {
    left: 'prev',
    right: 'next',
    center: 'title'
    },
    resources: this.state.rvs,
    resourceRender: function(resourceObj, labelTds, bodyTds) {
    labelTds.css('background-image', "url(" + resourceObj.header_image + ")");
    },
    resourceLabelText: 'Resources',
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, resource) {
    alert('clicked ' + date.format() + ' on resource ' + resource.id);
    },
    dayRender: function(date, cell){
    cell.append('<span>$40</span>');
    console.log(date.format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
    },
    select: function(startDate, endDate, jsEvent, view, resource) {
    // alert('selected ' + startDate.format() + ' to ' + endDate.format() + ' on resource ' + resource.id);
    },
    events: this.state.events,
    eventRender: function(event, element, view){
    },
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives'
});
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can. If you look at the HTML source of the calendar I think you'll see that what appear on screen to be a cell is in fact a visual effect caused by layering two different HTML tables on top of each other. There's no one HTML element that you could write content into which represents an individual cell on the calendar.

Comment: I see you want to write prices for the slots into each empty space. Perhaps instead you can have a placeholder event in each slot which displays the price, but which is removed once the slot is booked.

Comment: How do we add the placeholder event?

Comment: Same way you add any other events. Just make them a different colour or something so they're clearly different to the user's eye

Comment: Surely there is a better way of doing this?